# Assign oridinal number to unique data in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
ID  Time
0   100
1   100
2   200
3   200
4   500
5   500
6   890
...
```

I want to add a column of ordinal number based on column 'Time' in ascending order, like this:

```
ID  Time  Ordinal
0   100      1
1   100      1
2   200      2
3   200      2
4   500      3
5   500      3
6   890      4
...
```

Is there any elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`pd.dataframe.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html):

```
>>> df["Ordinal"] = df["Time"].rank(method="dense")  # Optionally, add .astype(int) to cast to int
>>> df
   ID  Time  Ordinal
0   0   100      1.0
1   1   100      1.0
2   2   200      2.0
3   3   200      2.0
4   4   500      3.0
5   5   500      3.0
6   6   890      4.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `factorize`

```
df['new'] =df.Time.factorize()[0]+1
df
Out[463]: 
   ID  Time  new
0   0   100    1
1   1   100    1
2   2   200    2
3   3   200    2
4   4   500    3
5   5   500    3
6   6   890    4
```